# Making the menu icon clickable from a curtain menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the starting components of a website header and curtain menu set up and working as intended. However, after clicking the menu button to bring down the curtain menu, I cannot seem to get the menu button to show up / be clickable from the curtain menu.

https://codepen.io/jnbull/pen/EerxEg

```js
function menuButton(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function toggleNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
  if (x.style.height === "100%") {
    x.style.height = "0%";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Global */

.white {
  color: #fff
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

header .menu {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .title h1 {
  margin: 21.5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header .title a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


/* Navigation */

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlayContent {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
a:active {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Header Start - Includes Title, Logo, and Menu -->
<header id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#top" class="logo"><img src="images/1x/Asset 
                     1.png" alt="Initials JB"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Menu Button -->
    <div class='menu' onclick="menuButton(this); toggleNav()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="title">
      <h1>
        <a href="#top">JADON BULL</a>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Header End -->
<!-- Navigation Start -->
<div class="container">
  <nav id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <div class="overlayContent">
      <a href="#">Overview</a>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Change "position: fixed" to "position: relative;" in your header CSS.

Comment: Do you want the header to be visible when the menu is open?

Comment: @ErikB Thanks! Could you explain how this works? Especially if I want my header to be fixed as I scroll once there is more content on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the link to the forked version of your code: 
https://codepen.io/jaiko86/pen/mGvyJQ

This will do what you want it to do with the menu button. I removed (commented out) the `menuButton()`, and changed the `z-index` of `.top`, which contains `.menu`. The thing about z-index is that it will change the stacking order of sibling elements, but you can't stack it on top of or below sibling elements of its ancestors.

For example, let's say I have the following set of elements:

```
<elem-a>
  <nested-a1>
  <nested-a2>
  <nested-a3>
</elem-a>
<elem-b>
  <nested-b1>
  <nested-b2>
  <nested-b3>
</elem-b>
```

In this example, changing `z-index` of `<nested-a1>` will only affect its stacking order among its siblings, `<nested-a2>` and `<nested-a3>`. It won't have any effect on `<elem-b>` or its children.

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I was misunderstanding.  For my knowledge on future projects, is there any way (maybe without using z-index) to lift a nested element above its parent’s sibling?  For example, lifting <nested-a3> in your example above <elem-b>? Or in my case, lifting only the menu button above the curtain menu?

Comment: @JadonBull I'd suggest putting ```.myNav``` in the the ```<header>``` at the same level as the menu button. I did just that here: https://codepen.io/jaiko86/pen/EerrvO . You can see the ```<nav>``` is now in the ```<header>```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing position to absolute on the parent container fixed it.

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```js
function menuButton(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function toggleNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
  if (x.style.height === "100%") {
    x.style.height = "0%";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Global */

.white {
  color: #fff
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

header .menu {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .title h1 {
  margin: 21.5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header .title a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


/* Navigation */

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlayContent {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
a:active {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Header Start - Includes Title, Logo, and Menu -->
<header id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#top" class="logo"><img src="images/1x/Asset 
                     1.png" alt="Initials JB"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Menu Button -->
    <div class='menu' onclick="menuButton(this); toggleNav()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="title">
      <h1>
        <a href="#top">JADON BULL</a>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Header End -->
<!-- Navigation Start -->
<div class="container">
  <nav id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <div class="overlayContent">
      <a href="#">Overview</a>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```